# How to validate inputs expression in DMN camunda

Tags: java, regex, validation, camunda

I searched `Camunda DMN API` but could not found the API which can validate `input expression`.

[Here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/dmn11/feel/language-elements/) is the doc for supported expression for `DMN inputs`

Consider following example, if there is a input column with `integer` datatype.

## |    x    |    o/p     |

## |   int   |     string |

|   < 9   |   "ABC"    |

|   10 <= |   "XYZ"     |   `NOT a valid expression for x`

And say by mistake user creates new rule with input(x) `"10 <="` which is NOT a valid expression.

And it only `throws exception` at time of evaluation of `DMN table`.

**What I want to do is to validate if expression is valid or not at time of add rule to DMN table using either camunda DMN API in JS or Java**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API directly for validating input entries. It follows the grammar of FEEL from the DMN 1.1 standard. You could use the [FEEL implementaion](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-engine-dmn/tree/master/feel-juel) that is used by the DMN engine to create some sort of validation. Or example see the [test suite](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-engine-dmn/blob/master/feel-juel/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/dmn/feel/impl/FeelExceptionTest.java) which does something similar.

Comment: Link was helpful. Found way for validation. Thanks :)

Comment: If I want to update single rule from dmn table using java code, do I have to replace whole dmn file with updated rule?

Comment: You could use the [DMN Model API](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model/) to get the rule you want to update by id and than change it accordingly. Maybe have a look at the [test suite](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model/blob/master/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/model/dmn/ExampleTest.java#L188)